# Android - How to go directly to previous activity in back stack and ignore the fragment backstack or remaining fragments in current activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

There are questions regarding back stack and `fragmentManager` but I didn't find any that have this similar use case.

So Here is my use case: on a tablet, I have the main activity on the left that acts as a navigation page, and fragments showing on the right when users click on things on the left. E.g. when clicking on `General`, the `general` page will be shown on the right. Let's say I navigate from `Homepage` to this `Settings` activity which has `General` and other settings, I show the `General` page on the right as default on the tablet (so that the right part won't be blank), and when I click on the back button, I want to go back directly to `Homepage` instead of showing the blank right part. I fixed this by:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    //some code
    if (isTabletLayout && supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount == 1) {
        supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()
    }
    super.onBackPressed()
    //some other code
}
```

However, even if I do this, I will see the right part flashes to blank and then I was shown the previous activity (in the example, the `Homepage`)

Now I'm wondering if I can just ignore that last fragment or delete the fragment back stack when there is only one left and directly show the previous activity?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about just calling `finish();` in `onBackPressed()` without first popping the Fragment back stack or calling `super.onBackPressed()`?

Comment: @0X0nosugar It worked!!!!!!! Thanks!!!!!!! I tried `finish()` and then `super.onBackPressed()` earlier so I thought `finish()` doesn't work. But calling `finish()` ALONE does the job! Thanks!!!

Comment: In your situation, the problem with also calling `super.onBackPressed()` is that this will make the `FragmentManager` remove the last `Fragment`. And `finish()` takes a tiny amount of time before showing any effects so in the meantime you see the last `Fragment` being removed

Comment: @0X0nosugar Yep. And this should be safe to do because the fragments left in the back stack will just get destroyed as the activity gets destroyed right?

Comment: Correct :-) Calling finish() will remove the Activity from the application's stack of Activities

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}
```

Just call finish() on onBackPressed() method.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way around by just calling `finish();`

**However** you shouldn't use your main activity as a navigation Tab. That's straight up bad UI and will lead to a bad UX.

Rearrange your UI now and avoid bigger problems in the future.

Comment: There are lots of examples where you will want the left side to act as a navigation screen. For example, email list, the left side shows email's preview, when you click on one, the detail is shown on the right. You also get to reuse fragments which I think is one of the reasons we have fragments...